# EFK ibtegration with springboot dependency vulnerability issue

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2, fluentd

I'm trying to integrate my spring-boot application with the EFK Docker instance.
So when I was searching for solutions or guidance for that, I found that I had to use
**Fluent Logger for Java** dependency. but when i check for the MVN Repository it seems the latest development of that library is 2019 and seems it has 2 vulnerabilities

[Fluent Logger repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fluentd/fluent-logger/0.3.4)

```
Vulnerabilities from dependencies:
CVE-2020-15250
CVE-2017-5929
```

So is it good to use dependencies that have these kinds of vulnerabilities, and are there any other alternative solutions to achieve my task?

Comment: If your application also uses Docker there are other approaches, and there are more FluentD appenders for Log4j2 (or logback/slf4j).

Comment: @M.Deinum spring App is not in docker, I'll try with others thanks for your input